# How does a recursive quadtree subdivision with concentric circles work?

Tags: javascript, quadtree

I have a quadtree and the subdivision currently works with the distance from the camera to the center of a child and the width of the child.

```
_LODCircles(pos){
        
    const height = pos.y;  //height of the camera above ocean
    const lodRadius = [];
    const minRadius = 40;  //radius of the smallest lod
    const radius0 = Math.abs(height) > minRadius ? Math.abs(height) : minRadius;
    const qtSize = 200000;  //the size of the quadtree
    const lodSize = Math.log(qtSize/radius0)/Math.LN2;  //calculate the lodsize

    for(let i = 0; i < lodSize; i++){
        lodRadius.push(radius0 * 2 ** i);
    }
                            
    return lodRadius;   
}


_GetChildCorners(child) {
    const corners = [];
    corners.push(new THREE.Vector3(child.bounds.min.x, 0, child.bounds.min.y));
    corners.push(new THREE.Vector3(child.bounds.min.x, 0, child.bounds.max.y));
    corners.push(new THREE.Vector3(child.bounds.max.x, 0, child.bounds.max.y));
    corners.push(new THREE.Vector3(child.bounds.max.x, 0, child.bounds.min.y));
    return corners;
}


//pos = cameraPosition
Insert(pos, scenePosition) {
    let lodCircles = this._LODCircles(pos);
    this._Insert(this.root_, pos, lodCircles);  
}


_Insert(child, pos, lodCircles) {       
/*
    //this works, but i want to make a subdivision with radial concentric lod circles
    const distToChild = this._DistanceToChild(child, pos, scenePosition);

    if ( distToChild < child.size.x && child.size.x > this._params.min_node_size ) {

        child.children = this._CreateChildren(child);
    
        for (let c of child.children) {
            this._Insert(c, pos, lodCircles);
        }
    }
*/

  ???   //  I still have no idea what the code for concentric circles for subdivision might look like   
    
}
```

But now I want to use concentric circles to get a subdivision like you can see here:

[image: radial quadtree subdivision]

I tried to do that with chat gpt but chat gpt keeps suggesting functional examples that don't work.

**Update regarding the comments:**

I have box3() in three.js. This is an AABB bounding box and I already use it in my quadtree. Every child in my quadtree has one.

I have now used the boundingBoxes for the subdivision.

```
_Insert(child, pos, lodCircles){
    

    const lod0radius = lodCircles[0];
    const lod0Center = pos; //camera position 
    const closestPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    child.bounds.clampPoint(lod0Center, closestPoint); 
    const squaredDistance = lod0Center.distanceToSquared(closestPoint);     


    if (squaredDistance <= lod0radius * lod0radius && child.size.x > lodCircles[0] ) {

        child.children = this._CreateChildren(child);

        for (let c of child.children) {
            this._Insert(c, pos, lodCircles);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I really like your idea! And it's also going in the right direction.

[image: Subdivision with boundingBoxes]

But what doesn't fit yet is that there are LOD transitions in which there is a 4:1 subdivision instead of just 2:1. I'm thinking how to fix that. I will probably need all sphere radii after all to ensure that the transitions from Lod to Lod number are only 2:1.
Your advices were very helpful. Maybe you also have a good idea for this that I can't see yet?

Comment: ChatGPT is a story writing service. not a programming tool. If you expect anything other than "plausible but in no way factual stories" when you ask it something, you're literally using it wrong. Break down your problem: a quad tree only needs to subdivide if there are too many items to fit in a leaf, so why would concentric circles matter?

Comment: Instead of doing a distance calculation, you do an AABB and circle intersection test to figure out which circle, well, intersects which quadrant. This really works for any shape. You subdivide based on a threshold, which is usually how many objects are to be contained within a single quadrant (a max depth termination is also always a good idea). In your example that threshold would be 1. There's definitely some possible optimizations because of the fact that the circles are concentric, but the basic algorithm will work either way.

Comment: The AABB thing sounds interesting. I added an update to my question. Do you mean something like that?